# datediff(dd,... returning month data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've come across this in a query:

```
[date_start] >= DATEADD(dd, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

I understand that this is in part removing the time element from the field, but can someone explain to me how this is returning the current month data without using the 'month' function?

Comment: Have a close look at the parameters. When you subtract the current day from the current_date you get the last day of the previous month: `2017-7-17 - 17 = 2017-06-31`. And this subtracts one less: `2017-07-17 - (17-1) = 2017-07-01`

Comment: the formula was designed to get the 1st date of the current month... deducting the current date and adding 1 day to start the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes the current day of the month (day(GetDate())+1) and subtracts it from the number of whole days since day 0.

```
[Date_start] >= 
DATEADD(dd, --Add Integer X to DateTime Y

-DAY(GETDATE()) + 1,  --X = - Current Day of Month + 1

DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) --Y = The number of days between day 0 and now.
                           --(in whole days to round out the 'time' part of the datetime)
```

There's no standard function to achieve this.

Yours is not much less intuitive than other methods I've seen, although using a negative number in date**add**() is confusing, as is the reliance on the result of the `datediff()` being implicitly converted from `int` to `datetime`.

Other Methods Here:  [SQL Server Helper - Date Functions](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-first-day-of-month.aspx)

Comment: A good tip for understanding any query is to break it down into it's constituent parts. Run `SELECT
 -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())` and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for that, nice concise answer I was looking for. Running the select on it was a good tip too, I hadn't thought of doing that. Much appreciated